# Xamarin Forms CollectionView ScrollTo when called externally

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have this control that is mainly a collectionview and occasionally I have to use changes elsewhere to scroll the collectionview, so I exposed a ScrollTo method which I am triggering when an event in another control is called.

I only tested on android.

I followed breakpoints and ScrollTo is being called but no scrolling happens,
(scrolling actually doesnt work also when the page is loaded, or when on appearing calls it in the page that implements the control, for the first one I saw the response, and since its a contentview and not contentpage I dont have OnAppearing to use)
I have an OnScrolled Event Attached that isn't called as well.

I am also sure it is meant to scroll as the index I am calling is not the one I have;

Exposed ScrollTo

```
public void ScrollToOffset(int Offset, bool animate = true)
        {
            int index = currentIndex + Offset;
            ScrollTo(index: index, animate: animate);
        }
```

Calling Code

```
public void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control.ScrollToOffset(1);
        }
```

Comment: are you executing on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, I am not calling it async so I dunno why it wouldn't be but either way I verified by calling through `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => collectionView.ScrollTo(index: index, animate: animate));`
I also made sure its nott a focusing thing, I called both through the calling class and internally `Control.Focus()` and `collectionView.Focus()`

Comment: I found out that my call to scroll from the page `OnAppearing()` does work when is reloaded by hot reload.